# how to draw route line on google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want draw vehicle route line on the map, accurately on the road , but my points update after 1 min. so existing code draws line overs the buildings and so on...
any body have some solution for this ? 
thanks in advance..

Comment: What have you got? The FAQ say at least a few lines of code help. To draw lines on the roads you need to use the Directions service which doesn't provide lines through buildings, so I've no idea what you're actually doing. Please update your question.

Comment: i think you are right , but i have no idea to use google direction service.

Comment: Start with the documentation. SO is not the place for a tutorial.